# GETH Always return the 0 balance

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

i was install the GETH and fully fast syncing with ethereum blocks.
see my screenshot.

`web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 7001298,
  highestBlock: 7001400,
  knownStates: 110459512,
  pulledStates: 110393584,
  startingBlock: 567719
}`

Then I tried to fetch balance.but it will return the 0 always.

`web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x59a5208B32e627891C389EbafC644145224006E8'),'ether').toString(10)`

in Etherscan u can see the balance of this address.
**https://etherscan.io/address/0x59a5208B32e627891C389EbafC644145224006E8**

so, why the geth retuns to 0 balance after syncing full blocks in main network i was run the geth with

**geth --rpc --datadir "/mnt/volume_sfo2_02" --syncmode "fast"**

Please help to find out this solutions.

Comment: You likely still need to complete the sync. You won't have all the transactional data until the sync completes since you're using `--syncmode "fast"`.

Comment: i have checked that it is already synced and it is continuously syncing with new blocks.but still not getting balance.it was return 0.

Comment: You ever figure this one out? having the same problem